# Java: Why isn't my file writing working?

Tags: java, file, io

I'm trying to write a file from my Java program, but nothing happens. I'm not getting any exceptions or errors, it's just silently failing.

```
        try {
            File outputFile = new File(args[args.length - 1]);
            outputFile.delete();
            outputFile.createNewFile();
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
            TreePrinter.printNewickFormat(tree, output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
```

Here is the `TreePrinter` function:

```
public static void printNewickFormat(PhylogenyTree node, PrintStream stream) {
    if (node.getChildren().size() > 0) {
        stream.print("(");
        int i = 1;
        for (PhylogenyTree pt : node.getChildren()) {
            printNewickFormat(pt, stream);
            if (i != node.getChildren().size()) {
                stream.print(",");
            }
            i++;
        }
        stream.print(")");
    }
    stream.format("[%s]%s", node.getAnimal().getLatinName(), node.getAnimal().getName());
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That code is guaranteed to at least create a (possibly empty) file or throw some exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close and / or flush your output stream:

```
TreePrinter.printNewickFormat(tree, output);
output.close(); // <-- this is the missing part
} catch (IOException e) {
```

Additionally, calling `delete()` / `createNewFile()` is unnecessary - your output stream will either create or overwrite an existing file.

Comment: In that case your node must be empty - nothing is written to the file. You can test whether that's the case (or you have some other issue) by printing something prior to close, e.g. `output.println("test");`

Answer (score 1):

flush the PrintStream.